# What to do first if you're manually editing files directly on a production server with no backups

Tags: deployment, version-control, development-environment, production-environment, devops

I realize this is fodder for being closed, but I'm having trouble finding this information elsewhere, and I'm sure others are as well.

The scenario:
You've been hired on to a web development team that is lacking every sort of "best practice" in their environment.  There's no version control, no backups, development is done using a basic text editor on the public facing production server itself (there's only one, it doesn't appear to have any recent OS patches, and it uses a database installed on the same server), etc.

My problem is that I can't seem to find any resources to reference that can tell me what to do if I was in this scenario.  Should I first take a backup of the database?  Version control?  Check for security holes?  What comes next?  What would the logical order of steps be if I wanted to take this somewhere meaningful?  Maybe this application could greatly benefit from implementing (insert buzzword), but it sounds like I'm 50 steps away from that goal, and I don't even know what those 50 steps look like.

In short, what's a good resource to utilize if I wanted to tackle going from a minimum viable environment and incrementally work towards something more reliable, secure, scalable, and so on?  Thanks!

Comment: My first thing would be to quit that place.

Answer (score 0):

I'd run from that place... However, if you choose to stay, I'd recommend talking with the rest of your team and coming up with what the end result should be.  They may be more receptive than you'd think.  Once you have an end goal, you can work incrementally towards that goal.  But everyone needs to have a say in this.

It's hard to make recommendations without knowing the environment and application...but I'll give it a shot.

What I'd do:
Make sure production is being backed up regurally and there's a DR plan in place.  Database, web site(s), any dependencies - everything you need to get the application(s) running on a new server.  Secure off-site backups would be ideal.

Set up a stage environment on a new server.  If you feel the DB instance should be on its own server (not web facing), put that on its own server.

Implement any version control system, load your code into it, and deploy it to the new stage environment.  I believe Visual Studio Team Services is free for up to 5 users.  If your team is larger than 5 people, get your company to spend the money.  But the 5 user limitation should be fine to set up a proof of concept.

Coordinate a cut over to promote the stage environment to production.  This takes care of the production server that hasn't been patched...and may be compromised.

Wipe out the old production server and use that as stage.

No matter how bad the environment, it can be fixed.  It will take time and will be painful for everyone involved.  But that just makes it so much more gratifying when you're done.